# In the SGR number 38 and 48, where do the 2 and 5 numbers come from?

Tags: colors, escape-characters

In multi-color-compatible terminals, one can set a color from a 256-color palette by using <kbd>ESC</kbd>`[38;5;Nm`, and any RGB color using <kbd>ESC</kbd>`[38;2;R;G;Bm`.

I've been wondering though, where do the "2" and "5" numbers come from and why exactly "2" and "5"?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/26665998/4228744 - "These extended modes are technically "undocumented" and are completely implementation defined."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `2` and `5` come from **`ITU T.416`** (the same as **`ISO 8613-6`**), entitled *Open Document Architecture (ODA) and Interchange Format: Character Content Architectures*.

Quoting from **`ISO/IEC 8613-6 : 1994 (E)`**, page 41:

> The first parameter element indicates a choice between:
>
> 0 implementation defined (only applicable for the character foreground colour)
>
> 1 transparent;
>
> 2 direct colour in RGB space;
>
> 3 direct colour in CMY space;
>
> 4 direct colour in CMYK space;
>
> 5 indexed colour.

and there are several paragraphs after that explaining what parameters would follow this parameter (but that wasn't the question).

Further reading:

- [Why only 16 (or 256) colors?](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/ncurses.faq.html#xterm_16MegaColors) (ncurses FAQ)
- [Can I set a color by its number?](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/xterm.faq.html#color_by_number) (xterm FAQ)